# Unicode re.sub() doesn't work with \g<0> (group 0)

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, regex-group

**Why doesn't the `\g<0>` work with unicode regex?**

When I tried to use `\g<0>` to insert a space before and after the group with normal string regex, it works:

```
>>> punct = """,.:;!@#$%^&*(){}{}|\/?><"'"""
>>> rx = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(punct))
>>> text = '''"anständig"'''
>>> rx.sub(r" \g<0> ",text)
' " anst\xc3\xa4ndig " '
>>> print rx.sub(r" \g<0> ",text)
 " anständig "
```

but with unicode regex, the space isn't added:

```
>>> punct = u""",–−—’‘‚”“‟„!£"%$'&)(+*-€/.±°´·¸;:=<?>@§#¡•[˚]»_^`≤…\«¿¨{}|"""
>>> rx = re.compile("["+"".join(punct)+"]", re.UNICODE)
>>> text = """„anständig“"""
>>> rx.sub(ur" \g<0> ", text)
'\xe2\x80\x9eanst\xc3\xa4ndig\xe2\x80\x9c'
>>> print rx.sub(ur" \g<0> ", text)
„anständig“
```

1. How do I get `\g` to work in unicode regex?
2. If (1) is not possible, how do I get the unicode regex input the space before and after a character in `punct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two errors.  First, you are not escaping `punct` like in the first example with `re.escape` and you have characters like `[]` that need to be escaped. And second, `text` variable is not unicode. Example that works:

```
>>> punct = re.escape(u""",–−—’‘‚”“‟„!£"%$'&)(+*-€/.±°´·¸;:=<?>@§#¡•[˚]»_^`≤…\«¿¨{}|""")
>>> rx = re.compile("["+"".join(punct)+"]", re.UNICODE)
>>> text = u"""„anständig“"""
>>> print rx.sub(ur" \g<0> ", text)
 „ anständig “
```