# How to find all capital and lower case occurrences of unicode character using regex and re.sub in Python?

Tags: python, regex, django, python-2.7, unicode

This is my code in django view (intentionally simplified)(Python 2.7):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
import re

def index(request):
    found_verses = [] 
    pattern = re.compile('ю')

    with open('d.txt', 'r') as doc:
        for line in doc:

            found = pattern.search(line)

            if found:
                modified_line = pattern.sub('!'+'\g<0>'+'!',line)
                found_verses.append(modified_line)

context = {'found_verses': found_verses}
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

`d.txt` (also utf-8) contains this one line (intentionally simplified):

```
1. Я сказал Юлию одному.
```

The above, when rendered, gives me the expected result:

```
1. Я сказал Юли!ю! одному.
```

When I change to a capital letter `pattern = re.compile('Ю')`, it also gives me the expected result:

```
1. Я сказал !Ю!лию одному.
```

But when I change to a group `pattern = re.compile('[юЮ]')` or `pattern = re.compile('[Юю]')` or `pattern = re.compile('[ю]')` or `pattern = re.compile('[Ю]')`, it gives me nothing. What I am trying to get is that:

```
1. Я сказал !Ю!ли!ю! одному.
```

Please help me to get this result. I've been struggling for more than a day and tried different configurations like `pattern = re.compile('[юЮ]', re.UNICODE)` and `pattern = re.compile('ю', re.UNICODE|re.I)` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427548/unicode-re-sub-doesnt-work-with-g0-group-0-python) and countless others but all in vain.

Comment: its hard to tell when you are using the actual characters ... can you add what the repr you see when you print is?eg `print repr(line)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I get this: `'1. \xd0\xaf \xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb \xd0\xae\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8e \xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd1\x83.'`

Comment: I think you just need to decode it to unicode with utf8 `line = line.decode("utf8")` then wi will work I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `unicode`s.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

```
with io.open('d.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as doc:
   ...
```

...

```
pattern = re.compile(u'[юЮ]', re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Thanks, Jordan! It works! But what is interesting it works even without `encoding='utf-8'` and without `re.UNICODE`. I am puzzled. So I guess `oi` does some magic. Could you aslo solve so I don't use  `pattern = re.compile(u'[Юю]')` but instead `pattern = re.compile(u'ю', re.I)`. As I understand, these should be equivalent, however the latter doesn't highlight the capital letter (and the other way around if I use capital, it doesn't highlight lower case). In other words, how to I use `re.I` with unicode?

Comment: Btw, I did watch the slide but it still doesn't fit in my silly head. Please read my comment to alexis.

Comment: You may need to set the locale properly with `locale`; I've never had to deal with Cyrillic so I can't say for certain. The `coding` header only applies to literals within the code. And you don't decode *to* UTF-8, you decode *from* UTF-8 to `unicode`.

Answer (score 1):

just a guess but try this

```
with open('d.txt', 'rb') as doc: #I guess you probably dont need the b flag for utf8 but meh
        for line in doc:
            line = line.decode("utf8")
             ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. Your code works only if I add `u` to `pattern = re.compile(u'[Юю]')`. Sorry, have to give it to @Ignacio, because his answer works as is. However, could you solve so I don't use  `pattern = re.compile(u'[Юю]')` but instead `pattern = re.compile(u'ю', re.I)`. As I understand, these should be equivalent, however the latter doesn't highlight the capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are using regular strings, not unicode strings. The `re` library needs to know how to treat the bytes in your RE. Try

```
re.compile(u'ю')
```

(Note that this is how @Ignacio does it in his answer).

Comment: Thanks, alexis, however `u` is not the only problem. Apparently I needed to `io` or explicitly decode the `line`. But then, why do we need `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top then... Even though the problem is solved, but I can't wrap my head around it all. You declare utf-8 at the top, you open a file which is utf-8, but then you have to decode it to utf-8 and you need to search with `u`. It just baffles me.

Comment: It's a bit strange, it's true. The main idea is that unicode is unicode, but utf-8 is just an encoding. So you don't decode to utf-8, you _encode_ to it or decode _from_ it. Ignacio's code is _decoding from_ the utf-8 encoding. As for the declaration at the top of your script, it only covers reading the script itself. When your script reads from a file, that could be another encoding (and after all, a script can read several files in different encodings). So you need to read the file correctly, and you need to create the search string (in the script) correctly.